# Aceder função JS

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, maps-javascript-api

Como consigo chamar uma função JS dentro de um evento de click, sendo que esta função está dentro de outra?

Segue o código:

```
    function setPin(geocoder, resultsMap, address, i) {
      geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address
      }, function(results, status) {
           if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
             var lat  = results[0].geometry.location.lat(); //obtem latitude
             var long = results[0].geometry.location.lng(); //obtem longitude

             var cod  = names[i].split(',')[0];
             var name = names[i].split(',')[1];

             var novaInfoWindow = criaInfoWindow(cod, name, address);

             var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                 map: resultsMap,
                 position: results[0].geometry.location
             });

             marker.addListener('click', function() {
                novaInfoWindow.open(resultsMap, marker);
             });

             function checkInPolygon(polygon) {
                myresult = google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(results[0].geometry.location, polygon);
             }
          } //status
      }); //geocoder.geocode
    }//setPin
```

O evento de click que chama a função está assim: (lembrando que o evento está dentro de outra função - `poly()` )

```
polygon.addListener('click', checkInPolygon(polygon));
```

O seguinte erro me retorna:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: checkInPolygon is not defined
```

Sei que o motivo deste erro é porque a função `checkInPolygon` está dentro de duas outras funções, mas não tenho prática o suficiente para saber como acessar essa função. Alguma ideia?

Comment: É necessário de alguma forma invocar `setPin` para depois invocar `checkInPolygon`, mas no seu caso ela está entro ainda de `geocoder.geocode`. Por que voce precisar ela direto?

Comment: @LucasCosta essa função verificará para mim se as localizações que estão sendo exibidas no mapa estão dentro de um polígono que foi desenhado no mapa. Por isso o motivo de estar dentro de outra função: há uma função onde se cria o poligono (`poly()`), e após este ser completado (evento `polygoncomplete`), recupera seus vértices e dentro deste evento, ainda há o evento de `click` que me possibilitaria saber "quem" está dentro do poligono através desta função que estou tentando acessar...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acebei conseguindo o que queria!

Como a função desejada (`chekInPolygon()`) estava encapsulada dentro de outras duas (`setPin()` e `geocoder.geocode()`), acabei por criar um evento do google maps dentro da o if mesmo, realizando o que era esperado.

**Antes**

```
function setPin(geocoder, resultsMap, address, i) {
      geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address
      }, function(results, status) {
           if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
             var lat  = results[0].geometry.location.lat(); //obtem latitude
             var long = results[0].geometry.location.lng(); //obtem longitude

             var cod  = names[i].split(',')[0];
             var name = names[i].split(',')[1];

             var novaInfoWindow = criaInfoWindow(cod, name, address);

             var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                 map: resultsMap,
                 position: results[0].geometry.location
             });

             marker.addListener('click', function() {
                novaInfoWindow.open(resultsMap, marker);
             });

             function checkInPolygon(polygon) {
                myresult = google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(results[0].geometry.location, polygon);
             }
          } //status
      }); //geocoder.geocode
}//setPin
```

**Depois**

```
function setPin(geocoder, resultsMap, address, i) {
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address
    }, function(results, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var lat  = results[0].geometry.location.lat(); //obtem latitude
            var long = results[0].geometry.location.lng(); //obtem longitude

            var cod  = names[i].split(',')[0];
            var name = names[i].split(',')[1];

            var novaInfoWindow = criaInfoWindow(cod, name, address);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: resultsMap,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });

            marker.addListener('click', function() {
                novaInfoWindow.open(resultsMap, marker);
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function(polygon) {
                polygon.addListener('click', function(){
                    myresult = google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(results[0].geometry.location, polygon);
                    if (myresult == true){
                        var respFim = results[0].geometry.location;

                        document.querySelector("#dash").innerHTML = respFim;
                    } //myresult == true

                    carrega();
                }); //click event
            }); //polygon complete event 
        } //status
    }); //geocoder.geocode
 } //setPin
```

Não consegui acessar a função, porém retornou de um método muito mais fácil.